# Is there a any way to get current stage (running, successfu,failure,aborted) of jenkins pipeline from another pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have two pipelines. Pipeline A (Application build) and pipeline B (App check). Pipeline A triggers the pipeline B and both runs simultaniously.
In pipeline B before a specific stage (run check) I need to verify if the pipeline A is successful. If not wait and check for some time till pipeline A gets finished. So pipeline B can proceed with the check if "A" is successful or exit with a failure.
What I need to know is, is there a any way to check the build status of pipeline A from pipeline B using pipeline "A"s build number. I passes the build number of Pipeline A to Pipeline B.

I looked if there's any env variable for status check but I couln'd find any.
I passes the build number of Pipeline A to Pipeline B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Pipeline B like below. Here you can use [waitUntil](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#waituntil-wait-for-condition) for waiting.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                        echo "Waiting"
                        def jobName = "JobA"
                        def buildNum = "92"
                        waitUntil { !isPending(jobName, buildNum) }

                        if(getStatus(jobName, buildNum).equals('SUCCESS')) {
                            echo "Job A is Successful"
                        } else {
                            echo "Job A Failed"
                        }
                    }
                   
               }
            }

        }
}

def isPending(def JobName, def buildNumber) {
    def buildA = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(JobName).getBuild(buildNumber)
    return buildA.isInProgress()
}

def getStatus(def JobName, def buildNumber) {
    def status = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(JobName).getBuild(buildNumber).getResult().toString()
    return status
}
```